# Check if a string is a permutation of a palindrome

Tags: python, palindrome

I see a couple of these on codereview but I was hoping my way hasn't yet been encountered:

```
def is_palindrome_permutation(strng):
    cache = set()
    for char in strng.lower():
        if not char.isalpha():
            continue
        if char in cache:
            cache.remove(char)
        else:
            cache.add(char)

    return len(cache) <= 1
```

Instead of maintaining any counts of characters to check for oddness or evenness, simply add and remove characters from a set. A character repeated an even number of times will be removed from the set; a character repeated an odd number of times will remain in the set. If the final set has a length less than or equal to one, it is a permutation of a palindrome.

Comment: I would call the function is_anagram_of_palindrome. Does it handle utf-8 or just a..z? You might want to state in a comment what you consider legal characters.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Documentation

You should definitely [add a docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/). It took me a few seconds to figure out was was going. Make sure to add some examples in the docstring as well.

## Naming

The name `cache` may not be the best name. Why? Let's look at the [definition of cache](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Cache_(computing)):

> is a hardware or software component that stores data so future requests for that data can be served faster

I don't really believe you use `cache` to serve stuff faster. I believe `odd_occuring_letters` is a better idea. (I don't like long names, maybe challenge yourself to a shorter name? Maybe `odd_letters`? Think about it.)

## (More) Comments

Even then, `odd_occuring_letters` isn't the most descriptive name, so you should include some comments as to what your code does. *Don't* over do it though.

Remember saying something like:

```
# Check the length of odd_occuring_letters is less than or equal to one.
return len(odd_occuring_letters) <= 1
```

Is **not** good. But saying:

```
# A word can have at most 1 odd character and still be palindrome.
return len(odd_occuring_letters) <= 1
```

explains to me *why* you return the length compared to one.

Answer (score 6):

You can take advantage of the [`set.symmetric_difference_update()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.symmetric_difference_update) operation, which does exactly your conditional add/remove.

```
def is_palindrome_permutation(s):
    unpaired_chars = set()
    for char in s.lower():
        if char.isalpha():
            unpaired_chars ^= set(char)
    return len(unpaired_chars) <= 1
```